# How to get text from <em> by python webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, caption

Is there any method for me to get the text "ABCD" as below HTML?
I just know get the emement , but have no idea about to get its text.

```
element1= find_element_by_xpath("//caption/em")
```

Then how can I get "ABCD", is there any method like gettext()?

```
<table class='1'>
    <caption>
        <em> ABCD </em>
    </caption>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element1= find_element_by_xpath("//caption/em")
element1.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

And I found Beautiful Soup will be more better to get text.

Answer (score 2):

Access the text using `text` attribute:

```
>>> element1.text
u'ABCD'
```

Comment: thanks. I've resolved my poeblem with get_attribute('innerHTML')