# How to get text beween < and > using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Further to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613439/how-to-get-text-from-em-by-python-webdriver).

```
<a id='1234' href ="http://www.google.com' class='alpha' > MY TEXT </a>
<caption>
    <em> ABCD </em>
</caption>
```

I want to extract text between  i.e

```
id='1234' href ="http://www.google.com' class='alpha'
```

How to do this using python and selenium.

Comment: If you use an xml parser parser, you can use the property `attrib` of the xml element. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib

Comment: I want to use selenium, because webpage is using javascript. I can see that link only when page is completely loaded. If I use beautifulsoup, it does not show any link

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
web_element.get_attribute(attribute_name)
```

method on the web_element object to get the value of any attribute present in a **web_element** in this case **id, href, class**.