# Get text from Selenium Webdriver instance in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can one get all the text of a Webdriver instance?

To get the text of a Webelement is straightforward, as explained for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613439/how-to-get-text-from-em-by-python-webdriver):

```
element1.text
```

or

```
element1.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

However, to get it from the Webdriver element I did not find similar solution. I just figured out the following two-step approach:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
```

but it seems to me that there has to be a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may probably try:

```
driver.get(url)
page_source = driver.page_source  # This gives you a 'str' containing the html source
print(page_source)
```

See also [Python Selenium accessing HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source).

If you need to parse the `page_source`, **BeautifulSoup4** is also a useful tool.